# Show list with JSON data in Xamarin.forms C#

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I want to put the JSON data in a list to show records to the user. But when I run the system the list only shows the project name twice, and not the JSON data.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("Http://www.eletrotechautomacoes.com.br");
string url = string.Format("/pontos/consulta.php");
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
List<ExchangeRates> listaProdutos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExchangeRates>>(result);

    this.LlistSpecials.ItemsSource = listaProdutos;
```

I think the error is in this line:

```
this.LlistSpecials.ItemsSource = listaProdutos;
```

My difficulty is to show the contents in the list. I need to do some conversion to the list to be shown? You know a procedure to display this list? It is currently returning the project name twice. I think it has something to do with the amount of JSON items, which are two as well.

File JSON:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "nome": "pendrive",
    "preco": "20.00",
    "tipo": "eletronico"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "nome": "Monitor",
    "preco": "250.00",
    "tipo": "eletronicos"
}]
```

Object:

```
public class ExchangeRates
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string preco { get; set; }
    public string tipo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Xaml or your ListView instantiation code?

Comment: it you don't provide a template for your list, it will just display the ToString() value of each object, which by default will be the name of the class

Comment: I think you haven't instantiated the list : List<ExchangeRates> listaProdutos = new List<ExchnageRates>();

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to display every properties in your Json objets in a ListView then you would need to create a Custom Cell. Documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance/#Custom_Cells).
If you are using textCell, you need to define the binding for which property to display.

If you want to display the "nome" for Example do so in your Xaml code:

```
  <ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextCell Text="{Binding nome}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```